# Measuring operation time nanoseconds and sometimes having unprecise results

Tags: c, unix, time

I want to measure cpu time of an operation nanoseconds resolution. I use

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID,&cpuTimeStart)
```

function before and after the operation and calculate difference in a loop. It usually says 5000 - 7000
nanoseconds but sometimes it becomes 30000, 50000 and even 80000 nanoseconds. Why is that, and if this is something like context switch, how can I ignore it and calculate more precisely?

Comment: Multitasking, as you suspect. Sometimes the operating system lets your program run the critical code at one go, other times it swaps out your process to let some other process work. The best way is to run the timing multiple times (the more the better), and calculate an average. (Printing out max/min/median time might be good too.)

Comment: I fact my real problem is, I want that operation to finish in a given time(for example 30000 nanoseconds). I call the function, measure the elapsed time and call nanosleep function for remaining time.This is why i give flag CLOCK_PROCESS_CPU_TIME not CLOCK_REALTIME.

Comment: [Ubuntu man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) says that *"these registers may differ between CPUs and as  a  consequence  these clocks may return **bogus results** if a process is migrated to another CPU."*

Comment: Yes, as i understand, i can't get the accurate results, but i learned that i don't need that much resolution. Thanks for your answers :)